# How to model this `has_one` `belongs_to` relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

`User` and `Organization` have a `many-to-many` association through `Relationship`. The `Relationship` model includes several boolean variables about the relationship, such as `moderator` (true/false) and `member` (true/false). Also, I added a boolean called `default` that sets the default organization.

I require a validation that **if (and only if) a user is a *member* of one or more organizations (`member == true`), one (and exactly 1) of these organizations has to have `default == true`.**

So basically this means that if a user is member of multiple organizations, one of these organizations needs to be the default ánd if the user is a member of multiple organizations such a default organization has to exist.

How to write this validation? My current validation generates the following error upon seeding:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "default"
LINE 1: ...ERE (user_id = 1) AND (member = 't' and default = ...
                                                   ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "relationships" WHERE (user_id = 1) AND (member = 't' and default = 't')
```

My implementation in the `Relationship` model:

```
validate :default
private
def default
  @relationships = Relationship.where('user_id = ?', self.user_id)
  @members = @relationships.where('member = ?', true)
  @defaults = @members.where('default = ?', true)
  # If more than 1 organization has been set as default for user
  if @defaults.count > 1
    @defaults.drop(0).each do |invalid|
      invalid.update_columns(default: false)
    end
  end
  # If user is member but has no default organization yet
  if !@defaults.any? && @members.any?
    @members.first.update_columns(default: true)
  end
end
```

**Update** On the looks of it, I understand I shouldn't model it this way, and instead should use a `has_one` `belongs_to` relationship as @DavidAldridge suggests in his answer. But I don't understand how to model this relationship (see my comment below the answer). Any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't really what validations are for. You might consider using a callback instead

Comment: What do your models look like? What relations did you define, exactly?

Comment: I've changed `validate :default` to `before_save :default` to turn it into a callback, but it generated the same error upon seeding. I will add the model relationships to the post.

Comment: And for the error you have, that's because `default` is a Postgres keyword. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809764/pgsyntaxerror-for-rails-application/31809807

Comment: Yes, thanks! Changing it to a callback and changing the name solved it. Will you add it as the answer, then I'll accept it?   I do sometimes hear bad things about callbacks (see for example http://samuelmullen.com/2013/05/the-problem-with-rails-callbacks/). Is there a better alternative for my use case?   Also, I couldn't find information whether with `before_save` the callback would get fired also when a new record is created? Or do I need to add *both* `before_save :newname` **and** `before_create :default`? Because the validation should fire for every change made in `Relationship`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: Or do I need to add *both* `before_save :newname` **and** `before_create :newname`?

Comment: @Marty I have nice suggestion for you. Just wait a couple of minutes for me to finish writing it please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this being difficult is that your data model is incorrect. The identity of a user's default organisation is an attribute of the user, not of the relationship, because there can be only one default per user. If you had a primary, secondary, tertiary organisation, then that would be an attribute of the relationship.

Instead of placing a "relationship is default for user" attribute on the Relationship, place a "default_relationship_id" attribute on the User so it ...

```
belongs_to :default_relationship
```

... and ...

```
has_one :default_organisation, :through => :default_relationship
```

This guarantees that:

1. Only one organisation can be the default for the user
2. There has to be a relationship between the user and its default organisation

You can also use :dependent => :nullify on the inverse association of :default_relationship, and easily test whether an individual relationship is the default based on whether:

```
self == user.default_relationship.
```

So something like:

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many   :relationships, :inverse_of => :user, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many   :organisations, :through    => :relationships, :dependent => :destroy
    belongs_to :default_relationship, :class_name => "Relationship", :foreign_key => :default_relationship_id, :inverse_of => :default_for_user
    has_one    :default_organisation, :through => :default_relationship, :source => :organisation


class Relationship  << ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user        , :inverse_of => :relationships
    belongs_to :organisation, :inverse_of => :relationships
    has_one    :default_for_user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :default_relationship_id, :inverse_of => :default_relationship, :dependent => :nullify

class Organisation << ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many   :relationships, :inverse_of => :organisation, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many   :users        , :through    => :relationships
    has_many   :default_for_users, :through => :relationships, :source => :default_for_user
```

Hence you can do such simple matters as:

```
@user = User.find(34)
@user.default_organisation
```

Default organisation is also easily eager-loaded (not that it couldn't be otherwise, but no scope is required to do so).

Comment: Thanks. So I place `has_one :default_organisation, :through => :default_relationship` in the `User` model. I place `belongs_to :default_relationship` in the `Organization` model. I don't actually need to create a `DefaultRelationship` model or do I? The `default_organisation_id` in the `User` model can also be blank (this requires a validation that looks at `Relationship`) if user is not a member of any organization. How to use `:dependent => :nullify`? What if a user's default organization gets deleted?; then if member of other organization that should become the default.

Comment: It starts with having a default_relationship_id in the User, and then the appropriate association to the relationship model. I added a fairly complete, non-syntax checked set of associations for the three models (no new models or classes required). If a user is no longer related to its default organisation then no default will be left, so another would have to be chosen.

Comment: Thanks, that's great! I implemented as suggested. Just to confirm: do I understand correctly that I don't need to add `default_for_stakeholder_id` to the relationships migration file? I haven't done so and modelled as you suggested. Then tested in the console: If I directly save a value for `@user.default_relationship_id` it works: `@user.default_organization` then produces the organization of the relationship with that id.

Comment: However, this didn't work in the console: `@user = User.first` `@user.default_organization` => nil. `@user.default_organization = Organization.first`. `@user.default_organization` => displays the organization. `@user.save`. `@user.reload`. The last still shows for `@user: default_relationship_id: nil`. Have I done something wrong? To `@user.default_organization = Organization.first` the console responded with: `BEGIN Relationship Exists SELECT 1 AS one FROM "relationships" WHERE ("relationships"."user_id" IS NULL AND "relationships"."organization_id" = 34) LIMIT 1 ROLLBACK`.

Comment: No boolean should be required, just an id on User for the relationship that links the user to the organisation that is to be the default.

Comment: Thanks David, then I belief I have modelled it correctly. Any idea why what I did in the console might not have worked? Is `@user.default_organization = Organization.first` perhaps not the correct way to set a default_organization for a user?

Comment: I think the behaviour for that might depend on whether there was already a relationship between the user and the org. It would be worth checking both situations.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not it (checked both situations). For example, I tried: `user=User.find(10)` => returns user with default_relationship_id nil. `user.default_organization = user.relationships.first.organization` => returns the organization of that relationship with the Rollback as in my previous comment. `user.default_organization` => returns the organization. `user`  => user with default_relationship_id nil. `user.save` => true. `user.reload` => user with default_relationship_id nil. `user.default_organization` => nil.

Comment: How about setting default_relationship instead of default_organisation?

Comment: Thanks, it works with: `user=User.find(11)` `user.default_relationship=user.relationships.first` `user.save` `user.reload` => default_relationship_id has value. `user_default_organization` => the organization of the relationship. Do you think `user.default_organization = ...` does not work because I have done something wrong or is that perhaps just not the right way to set the default_organization and should this be done via identifying the relationship with that organization?

Comment: I'm not sure -- I usually look at the SQL statements to try and reverse-engineer the thinking of ActiveRecord in these situations.

Answer (score 2):

@Brad Werth's correct that your `validate` method would work better as a callback.

I'd recommend something like this in your **Relationship** model:

```
before_save :set_default

private

  def set_default
    self.default = true unless self.user.relationships.where(member: true, default: true).any?
  end
```

This should enforce that a user's relationship is set to default if none of the user's other relationships already are.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this does not take into account that `default` (or `is_default`) can only be `true` for `member: true` organizations. Suppose there's no default organization (e.g., because the default organization's account got deleted) and the user would save a relationship with an organization of which it is not a member. Then here it would still set `default` to `true` for that organization of which it is not a member.

Answer (score 1):

Change `default` to `is_default` (as pointed out by another user in comments, `default` is postgres keyword). Create separate migration for this. (Or you could quote it everywhere if you prefer to leave it be as it is.)

Then, there are two points.

First, why you need to check for single `is_default` organization every time? You just need to migrate your current data set, and then keep it consistent.

To migrate your current data set, create migration and write something like this there:

```
def self.up
  invalid_defaults = Relationship.
    where(member: true, is_default: true).
    group(:user_id).
    having("COUNT(*) > 1")

  invalid_defaults.each do |relationship|
    this_user_relationships = relationship.user.relationships.where(member: true, is_default: true)
    this_user_relationships.where.not(id: this_user_relationships.first.id).update_all(is_default: false)
  end
end
```

Just make sure to run this migration in off-peak hours, as it could take considerable amount of time to finish. Alternatevely, you can just run that code snippet from the server console itself (just test in in development environment beforehand, of course).

Then, use callback (as rightfully suggested by another commenter) to set the default organization when the record is updated

```
before_save :set_default

private

def set_default
  relationships = Relationship.where(user_id: self.user_id)
  members = relationships.where(member: true)
  defaults = members.where(is_default: true)

  # No need to migrate records in-place

  # Change #any? to #exists?, to check existance via SQL, without actually fetching all the records
  if !defaults.exists? && members.exists?
    # Choosing the earliest record
    members.first.update_columns(is_default: true)
  end
end
```

To take the case into account where Organization is being edited, callback to organization should be added as well:

```
class Organization
  before_save :unset_default
  after_commit :set_default

  private

  # Just quque is_default for update...
  def remember_and_unset_default
    if self.is_default_changed? && self.is_default
      @default_was_set = true
      self.is_default = false
    end
  end

  # And now update it in a multi-thread safe way: let the database handle multiple queries being sent at once,
  # and let only one of them to actually complete, keeping base in always consistent state
  def set_default
    if @default_was_set
      self.class.
        # update this record...
        where(id: self.id).
        # but only if there is still ZERO default organizations for this user
        # (thread-safety will be handled by database)
        where(
          "id IN (SELECT id FROM organizations WHERE member = ?, is_default = ?, user_id = ? GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*)=0)",
          true, true, self.user_id
        )
    end
  end
```

Comment: Suppose a user wants to change their default organization. 1) Saves the `is_default` value for old organization to `false`. 2) `Before_save` of `is_default` of the new organization, it sets `is_default` is `true` for a random member organization. 3) Saves the `is_default` value for new organization to `true`. Result: two organizations with `true` value. A similar problem exists if I replace `before_save` with `after_save`.

Comment: Having this check in user won't cut it anyway, you will still have state where user has 2 default organizations, before he is saved again (and this before_save/validate method of user is called). I'll update my answer with solution.

Comment: @Marty Updated. You might say this is a complex approach, but delegating check to the database itself is the only way you can be sure that your data is consistent in every given moment. Otherwise with more or less high requests more second rate you will often hit cases where there will be 0 or 2+ default organizations. By the way, `#first` isn't random too, it selects first (by ID) record every time. You also need to take into consideration the case where user is deleted from organization (and/or organization itself is deleted), you can use similar solution.